# Nested Set Tree Model SQL, number of direct children and depth

Tags: mysql, nested-sets

I am trying to create a MySQL query that will return a list of nodes, the depth of each node, and how many direct children each node has.

The reason for this is I am needing to populate a binary tree with the "next available" spot, meaning the highest-level node that has fewer than 2 direct children.

I've found queries that will return depth, and I've found queries that will return the number of direct children a node has, but I am not enough of an SQL genius to combine the two queries into a single query. I am using CakePHP, by the way.

My table structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `nodes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `f_id` int(11),
  `parent_id` int(11),
  `lft` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rght` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastadd` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What I hoping to find is the following:

Provide a list of nodes that have less than 2 direct children, ordered by the lowest depth, fewest children, and oldest lastadd date.

Any help would be appreciated.